# "PropertyChange" is not firing up when text is changed or inserted in Textbox present inside my view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have two TextBoxes inside my View on which I am trying to implement a simple validation using MVVM design pattern.The issue is even when my ViewModel is implementing Inotification Changed interface and the property is bound tot the text property of the TextBox,on entering text propertyChange event never fires.I don't know where I have gone wrong.Please help.Its been bugging me for quite a while.

ViewModel :

```
 class TextBoxValidationViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private readonly TextBoxValidationModel _textbxValModel;
        private Dictionary<string, bool> validProperties;
        private bool allPropertiesValid = false;

        private DelegateCommand exitCommand;
        private DelegateCommand saveCommand;

        public TextBoxValidationViewModel(TextBoxValidationModel newTextBoxValObj)
         {
            this._textbxValModel = newTextBoxValObj;
            this.validProperties = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            this.validProperties.Add("BuyTh", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("SellTh", false);


        }


        public string BuyTh
        {
            get { return _textbxValModel.BuyTh; }
            set
            {
                if (_textbxValModel.BuyTh != value)
                {
                    _textbxValModel.BuyTh = value;
                    base.OnPropertyChanged("BuyTh");
                }
            }
        }

        public string SellTh
        {
            get { return _textbxValModel.SellTh; }
            set
            {
                if (_textbxValModel.SellTh != value)
                {
                    _textbxValModel.SellTh = value;
                    base.OnPropertyChanged("SellTh");
                }
            }
        }



        public bool AllPropertiesValid
        {
            get { return allPropertiesValid; }
            set
            {
                if (allPropertiesValid != value)
                {
                    allPropertiesValid = value;
                    base.OnPropertyChanged("AllPropertiesValid");
                }
            }
        }


        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string error = (_textbxValModel as IDataErrorInfo)[propertyName];
                validProperties[propertyName] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? true : false;
                ValidateProperties();
                CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                return error;
            }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                return (_textbxValModel as IDataErrorInfo).Error; 
            }
        }

        public ICommand ExitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (exitCommand == null)
                {
                    exitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Exit);
                }
                return exitCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (saveCommand == null)
                {
                    saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save);
                }
                return saveCommand;
            }
        }



        #region private helpers

        private void ValidateProperties()
        {
            foreach (bool isValid in validProperties.Values)
            {
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    this.AllPropertiesValid = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            this.AllPropertiesValid = true;
        }

        private void Exit()
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }


        private void Save()
        {
            _textbxValModel.Save();
        }

    }

}
#endregion
```

## Model :

```
  class TextBoxValidationModel : IDataErrorInfo
    {

        public string BuyTh { get; set; }
        public string SellTh { get; set; }

        public void Save()
        {
            //Insert code to save new Product to database etc 
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string validationResult = null;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "BuyTh":
                        validationResult = ValidateName();
                        break;
                    case "SellTh":
                        validationResult = ValidateName();
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new ApplicationException("Unknown Property being validated on Product.");
                }
                return validationResult;
            }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }


        private string ValidateName()
        {

            return "Entered in validation Function";
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase abstract Class :

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Application Start event code:

```
   private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            textboxvalwpf.Model.TextBoxValidationModel newTextBoxValObj = new Model.TextBoxValidationModel();
            TextBoxValidation _txtBoxValView = new TextBoxValidation();
            _txtBoxValView.DataContext = new textboxvalwpf.ViewModel.TextBoxValidationViewModel(newTextBoxValObj);
      //      _txtBoxValView.Show();

        }
    }
```

## View Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="textboxvalwpf.TextBoxValidation"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:textboxvalwpf.Commands"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:textboxvalwpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TextBoxValidation" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="86,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=BuyTh, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="88,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=SellTh,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label x:Name="label_BuyTh" Content="Buy Th" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71"/>
        <Label x:Name="label_SellTh" Content="Sell Th" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,117,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If anyone could quickly have a look on these code blocks.That would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You commented out the line where you show the window. Is that because two windows were showing?

Comment: @EdPlunkett : Yes indeed.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. You create an instance of your view with a viewmodel, then you throw it in the garbage and let the application show its own instance that you never bothered to initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App.xaml, you'll find a `StartupUri` attribute. By default, it looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="WPFTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

If you renamed MainWindow.xaml to TextBoxValidation.xaml, as I think you did, it'll look like this:

```
             StartupUri="TextBoxValidation.xaml">
```

Your application will automatically create an instance of that `StartupUri` window and show it. That'll be the application's main window, so the application will shut down when it closes.

That instance won't have a viewmodel, because nothing in your code gives it one. You are creating your own instance of the window, giving it a viewmodel, and then doing nothing with it because another instance is being shown. I imagine you thought just creating the window was enough to show it, but that's not what's happening at all. Before you commented out the `Show()` call, you did have one window with a working viewmodel that did the validation and updated the viewmodel properties.

Let the App create the window the way it wants to.

A quick, simple fix is to delete that `Startup` event handler from `App` and move your viewmodel creation code into `TextBoxValidation`'s constructor:

```
public TextBoxValidation()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textboxvalwpf.Model.TextBoxValidationModel newTextBoxValObj = new Model.TextBoxValidationModel();

    this.DataContext = new textboxvalwpf.ViewModel.TextBoxValidationViewModel(newTextBoxValObj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ed.This is fixed now.I accept this as answer for the better explanation.